# Group By in django 1.8

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have the next structure in my django app:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want select the earliest time of each name, in database like:

```
 ╔═════╤══════╤════════════╗
 ║ id  │ name │    time    ║
 ╠═════╪══════╪════════════╣
 ║  1  │   a  │ 2018-09-10 ║
 ║  2  │   a  │ 2018-09-11 ║
 ║  3  │   b  │ 2018-09-10 ║
 ║  4  │   b  │ 2018-09-11 ║
 ╚═════╧══════╧════════════╝
```

Then the result should be:

```
 ╔═════╤══════╤════════════╗
 ║ id  │ name │    time    ║
 ╠═════╪══════╪════════════╣
 ║  1  │  a   │ 2018-09-10 ║
 ║  3  │  b   │ 2018-09-10 ║
 ╚═════╧══════╧════════════╝
```

I know raw-sql is a solution, but is it possible to use django query expressions?  I'm using django 1.8. 
Any help please.

Comment: This does not look like a GROUP BY, since then the `id` would not be part of the result. Do you only want the *earliest* `time`, or the "earliest" object?

Comment: the earliest (time, name) tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with:

```
from django.db.models import Min

A.objects.values('name').annotate(
    min_time=Min('time')
).order_by('name')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` object that contains dictionaries: in this case it will look like:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'a', 'min_time': date(2018,09,10)},
           {'name': 'b', 'min_time': date(2018,09,10)}]>
```

So you can iterate over the queryset, and thus process the dictionary elements.

Comment: yes it works, thanks. but if there has more fields:(id,name,fname,time), and I need the earliest (time, name, ftime) tuple, then will be wrong.